# xelatex doesn't support shade ball?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

I just found that the code below couldn't be compiled correctly with xelatex, but everything was as expected with pdflatex:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand\matchstick[3]{
    \ifnum#3=1
    {
        \fill [brown!30!white] (#1,#2) rectangle (#1+3.8,#2+0.2);
        \shade[ball color=red] (#1+3.75,#2+0.1) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.22cm);
    }
    \fi
    \ifnum#3=2
    {
        \fill [brown!30!white] (#1,#2) rectangle (#1+0.2,#2+3.8);
        \shade[ball color=red] (#1+0.1,#2+3.75) ellipse (0.22cm and 0.25cm);
    }
    \fi
    \ifnum#3=3
    {
        \fill [brown!30!white] (#1,#2) rectangle (#1-3.8,#2+0.2);
        \shade[ball color=red] (#1-3.75,#2+0.1) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.22cm);
    }
    \fi
    \ifnum#3=4
    {
        \fill [brown!30!white] (#1,#2) rectangle (#1+0.2,#2-3.8);
        \shade[ball color=red] (#1+0.1,#2-3.75) ellipse (0.22cm and 0.25cm);
    }
    \fi
}
\matchstick{2}{0}{1};
\matchstick{6}{-2}{3};
\matchstick{0}{0}{2};
\matchstick{-2}{0}{4};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

With pdflatex, the result is:
[image]

But with xelatex, the shade part is missing:

[image]

I wonder if there's any ways to solve it? thx

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  This should be fixed in the latest version of PGF (see the [issue here](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/928)).  Update your system

Comment: thx for answering. It really works! I updated my pdf version to 3.1.7a.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved by a software update.